# How to Pause without Blocking the UI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a click event which causes the phone to vibrate once a button is clicked. This generally works great, except sometimes the vibration doesnt stop until I completely close the application. I would like to give the application time to complete its vibration and then continue with the rest of the method, but I do not want to block the UI at all. How might I accomplish this

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Button vibration
    if (Settings.EnableVibration.Value)  //boolean flag to tell whether to vibrate or not
    {
        VibrateController.Default.Start(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        //place vibration stop here?
    }        

    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new uri("/NewPage.xaml", UriKind.Relate)); 
}
```

I have already tried  VibrationController.Default.Stop(); but this completely eliminates the vibration all together. Is there a way to simply wait until after the vibration has completed to then navigate to a new page, or do whatever other action the method should perform? Any reccomendations or advice on this implementation or other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use asynchrony to prevent blocking the UI.  Rather than actually blocking the UI thread you need to schedule an action to happen again 100ms from now.  Adding a continutation to a `Task.Delay` call can do just that:

```
void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Action navigate = () =>
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new uri("/NewPage.xaml", UriKind.Relate));
    if (Settings.EnableVibration.Value)  //boolean flag to tell whether to vibrate or not
    {
        VibrateController.Default.Start();
        Task.Delay(100).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            VibrationController.Default.Stop();
            navigate();
        });
    }
    else
        navigate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What if in fact I did not want to navigate to a new page, but simply pause while the vibration occurred. Is this ok

    `if (Settings.EnableVibration.Value)  //boolean flag to tell whether to vibrate or not
            {
                VibrateController.Default.Start(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(40));
                Task.Delay(45).ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    VibrateController.Default.Stop();
                });
            }`
The VibrationController Start method requires a TimeSpan parameter.

Comment: Also, will setting `Delay` to a longer time than `Start` ensure that the vibration is complete before moving to the next process?

Comment: @Matthew If you don't want to do anything after the vibration stops then just pass in the timespan and don't do anything else; you're done.  If you want to do something *right* when the vibration stops then you'll want to ensure you delay for less time than the timespan you pass so that you can run code when you explicitly stop it.

Comment: When you say just pass in the time span and dont do anything else, you mean simply saying `VibrateController.Default.Start(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))` in the `If` statement and thats it? Currently I was doing that but sometimes the vibration got stuck on vibrating without stopping. And yes, in all cases I need to perform an action after the vibration, sometimes navigating to a new page and other times just running code in the method itself. I also need to perform an action on another click event, so I would Delay for 50 milliseconds while vibrating for 100? I am kind of confused on this.

Comment: @Matthew I would think the code is rather self explanatory.  If you want to run code after a period of time, run it in a continuation of a `Delay` call.  Set it to whatever time you want to delay.  You can stop the vibration in the continuation, or through passing a timespan, whichever you want.

Comment: OK that clears it up a little, I've never used `Delay` before so I am unsure of how exactly it works. I'll certainly give it a try! So the `Delay` is called after the `VibrateController` has told the device to vibrate for a certain amount of time. I think it was getting confused on running the code while the vibration was still occuring and so the vibration was getting stuck.

Comment: @Matthew Delay just creates a task that is completed after the period of time provided; that's it.

Answer (score 0):

.NET wraps this functionality up conveniently in the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc221403%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class.

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    // Create backgroundworker
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    // Attach event handler
    bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;

    // Run Worker
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Do background stuff here
}
```

It also has support for progress updates and triggers an event on completion, as far as I know, this functionality extends to windows phone. All of this is covered in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc221403%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) article.

I would guess what you want to do is call vibrate in the BackgroundWorker, and you can listen for the RunWorkerCompletedEvent which will fire when it is finished. Also, you can happily pause this "thread" and it will not interfere with the UI.