# How to Wait Before Enabled a Control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a button in my WelcomePage, but I would like to wait for about 3 seconds before I allow the user to press it. This is so that the user is forced to read a quick little informative statement. I am making the button disabled by default in xaml and then in my loaded event I would like to start the timer and when 3 seconds has passed enable the button. From referencing a previous question here [How to Pause without Blocking the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231900/how-to-pause-without-blocking-the-ui/19231984?noredirect=1#comment28495285_19231984) I have the following but I am getting an `UnauthorizedAccessException` when attempting to enable the button

WelcomePage.xaml

```
<Button x:Name="welcomeButton" IsEnabled="False" Content="Welcome" Click="welcomeButton_Click"/>
```

WelcomePage.xaml.cs

```
void WelcomePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0)).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            welcomeButton.IsEnabled = true; //UnauthorizedAccessException error
        });
}
```

Is there a better method of doing this? All the user is doing on this page is reading a quick statement, so is it necessary to block the UI thread? Any suggestions or advice in this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to marshal the context back to the UI thread:

```
Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0)).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        welcomeButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Note that in Windows Phone 8, you can use async/await instead.  This should also work in 7.5 via the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package:

```
async void WelcomePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0));
    welcomeButton.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: This worked great. I haven't used await/async before. Could you give some background info on what exactly is happening here?

Comment: @Matthew There's a lot of info online about it - it's a lot more complex than what can be written into a comment, though.

Answer (score 2):

As Reed said in Windows Phone 8 this method will,

```
async void WelcomePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0));
     welcomeButton.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

solve your issue.

For learning more about this async / await you can use this 
 [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx)