# How to Pause App without Blocking UI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am going back to perform a few updates in a Windows Phone 7 app, and one of them includes plausing the application for a split second without blocking the UI. I'm not sure of the best way to do this. In Windows Phone 8 I referenced [How to Pause without Blocking the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231900/how-to-pause-without-blocking-the-ui) in which I did

```
void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Settings.EnableVibration.Value)  //boolean flag to tell whether to vibrate or not
    {
        VibrateController.Default.Start();
        Task.Delay(100);
    }
    ...
}
```

But `Task.Delay` I have not found in Windows Phone 7. Any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: Using a background thread, or whatever. It doesn't seem like you're doing anything there, besides pausing ... so, why would you like to pause without blocking the ui? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by "Pause app without blocking UI". What exactly do you need to "pause"? Is this a game that needs the UI to work while the game itself is paused? Or are you looking to pause the execution of something that is happening in the background?

Comment: I'm looking to pause the execution of something. The trouble I'm having now is that sometimes (actually quite a lot of times) when a button is clicked and I have a pause and then continue with something else (such as a page navigation) the vibration fails to stop and continues endlessly until I am forced to close the app to stop it. I have no idea why either.

Answer (score 0):

This works in windows 8 and my guess is that it will work for you too. If you have a constantly running process in the background, using a task, you can do this:

Define something that is running in the background:

Define a task and a bool to flip when you want to pause

```
    Task doStuff;
    static bool pauseTask = false;
```

Define the task where needed:

```
    doStuff = new Task(LoopForMe);
    doStuff.Start();
```

function that just does something

```
    private async static void LoopForMe()
    {
        //Keep thread busy forever for the sake of the example
        int counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            //Define pauseTask as a static bool. You will flip this
            //when you want to pause the task
            if (pauseTask)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100000);
                pauseTask = false;

            }

            Debug.WriteLine("working... " + counter);

            counter++;
            //Do something forever
        }
    }
```

And in your event, you can flip the bool:

```
    pauseTask = true;
```

I have to point out a few flaws in this however. I would find a way to determine when the task, that is supposed to "pause" background running code, be able to unlock the background thread. This example just forced the thread to wait for something for a set amount of time. I would flip the bool back and forth based on the code that is supposed to "block" it. In other words, block and unblock the thread as needed rather than rely on a timer. This approach should keep you UI still working while the work in the Task (a.k.a. thread) from doing any work for a preset amount of time.

There are a lot of pitfalls here. How do you make a thread wait without a timer? Now you are getting into more complicated thread wait logic. The benefit of the code above is that it is in a loop. How do you do this if it is not? Unfortunately you posed your question fairly vaguely so I really do not know what exactly you are trying to "pause". Please use the above code as a starting point.